# How to do square by height css

Tags: css

I need to make the width and height of the block dynamically equal.
But they were equal to the height of the block.

For the width i can write:

```
width: 100%;
padding-bottom: 100%;
position: absolute;
left: 0;
top: 0;
```

and block will be Square;

How i can do the same but for height?

some like:

```
height: 100%;
padding-right: 100%;
position: absolute;
left: 0;
top: 0;
```

thats not working

Comment: [`aspect-ratio`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/aspect-ratio).

Answer (score 0):

You can probably use the `vmin` unit. You can also use `aspect-ratio:` but it is not as widely supported.